# Bowl refill tube is constantly running into overflow tube

Tags: toilet

Bowl refill tube is running constantly into the overflow tube.

Comment: Turn water off.

Comment: Check refill valve... It's jammed or needs replacing.

Answer (score 5):

Gently lift the float and see if the water flow stops, if not replace the assembly; if it stops adjust the water height adjustment screw/knob.